# Operation "@" in multiply vectors gives Syntax Error

Tags: python

When I tried used in Google Colab this part code:

```
def costFunction(X, Y, theta):
    scalar=1;
    '''
    Calcular la Least Square Cost Function.
    Devolver la funcion calculada.
    '''
    X=np.insert(X.T, 0, np.ones(X.shape[1]), 1)
    theta=theta.T
    cost = 0.5 @ (X @ theta-Y.T).T@(X@theta-Y.T)+theta.T@scalar@theta
    return cost
```

Gives the error:

```
 >   File "<ipython-input-8-c78bf44930a0>", line 9
    >     cost = 0.5 @ (X @ theta-Y.T).T@(X@theta-Y.T)+theta.T@scalar@theta

               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The `@` operator is matrix multiplication.  0.5 is not a matrix.  Were you just trying to so a scalar multiply?  That's the regular `*` operator.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code did not have a syntax error on cpython 3.8.6,

Comment: Attempting to use the matrix multiplication operator with a scalar wouldn't be a SyntaxError, however - it would presumably be a TypeError or other such runtime error.  This seems more like the code is running on a Python version too old to have the `@` operator, although I'm not sure how you'd manage that on Colab.

Comment: @jasonharper - I was wondering something similar. Matrix multiplication has been around since python 3.5 which released in 2015. OP would do well to check ipython version, but its likely newer than that.

Comment: After importing `sys`, do `print(sys.version)` and post that here.

Comment: Cierto, lo tenia en Python 2.0, Gracias!!!